# How to make sure, Bitcoin private key and bitcoin address generator tools are generating valid key pair?

Tags: address-generation, validation

I find lots of `tools/scripts` written in `python` which can generate `random number` then using this `random number` it generates `Bitcoin Private key(WIF) -> Bitcoin Address pair`.

I have tried verifying few pairs using `www.bitaddress.org` >> `Wallet Details` by entering `WIF key` and verifying with output `address`.

But How can one make sure, the tools/scripts will always `generate valid address and key pair` ?

or is this like this way

if it generates one `valid` `address and key pair` it means all the future `address and key pairs` will be `valid` ?

i was looking at this **https://github.com/shirriff/bitcoin-code**

from `makeAddr.py`

```
import random, keyUtils
private_key = ''.join(['%x' % random.randrange(16) for x in range(0, 64)])
print keyUtils.privateKeyToWif(private_key)
print keyUtils.keyToAddr(private_key)
```

i know random number/string generated using this method is not very much secure, but i am talking in terms of `valid WIF and address pair`.

Comment: Read the rfc's and write your own is only real way. There could be bugs? But outside of that this is good question. I think bitcoin.org recommends some.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make sure that the private is lower than 1.158 * 10^77 (`115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337`) and

In your case you could do

```
 import random, keyUtils 
 private_key = ''.join(['%x' %random.randrange(16) for x in range(0, 64)]) 
 print keyUtils.privateKeyToWif(private_key)
 print keyUtils.keyToAddr(private_key)

 from ecdsa.curves import SECP256k1
 decoded_private_key = int(private_key,16)
 if decoded_private_key > 0 and  decoded_private_key < SECP256k1.generator.order():
     print 'valid'
 else:
     print 'invalid'
```

Comment: File "mycode\bitcoin-code-master\makeAddr.py", line 8, in <module>
    if decoded_private_key > 0 and  decode_private_key < SECP256k1.generator.order():
NameError: name 'decode_private_key' is not defined

Comment: dang, idk how i too missed that.